# pandas 0.20.3 DataFrame behavior changes for pyspark.ml.vectors object in a column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, explode

The following code works in pandas 0.20.0 but not in 0.20.3:

```
    import pandas as pd
    from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors

    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4], 
                       'B': [1,2,3,4], 
                       'C': [1,2,3,4],
                       'D': [1,2,3,4]},
                       index=[0, 1, 2, 3])
    df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(Vectors.dense([x["A"], x["B"]])), axis=1)
```

This produces from pandas 0.20.0:

```
                0
    0  [1.0, 1.0]
    1  [2.0, 2.0]
    2  [3.0, 3.0]
    3  [4.0, 4.0]
```

but it is different in pandas 0.20.3:

```
         0    1
    0  1.0  1.0
    1  2.0  2.0
    2  3.0  3.0
    3  4.0  4.0
```

How can I achieve the first behavior in 0.20.3?